# How to load configuration at startup in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have some configuration values in a YAML file that needs loaded when my app starts up.  The values need to be accessed in a few different places (both in a few models and a few controllers).  What is the best way to load, store, and access these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An initializer. John Nunemaker posted the one he uses for Harmony [over on gist](http://gist.github.com/230531).

So in that example harmony.rb would go in config/initializers and harmony.yml would just be in config.

Answer (score 5):

You can do as follows

create file yml example test.yml :

```
key: 936QQ84d3c4m8Y4Y
```

create file in config/initializers.

```
test = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/test.yml")
KEY = test["key"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this Gem "mc-settings" that manages application settings from YML files and allows overrides based on Rails environment, etc.

https://github.com/modcloth/mc-settings